# Does it matter if I have a "&" right after "?" in my url?

Tags: url, get

Does it matter if I have a "&" right after "?" in my url?
For example:
http://www.blah.com/blah.php?&key=23

Would any browser get stumped by that? Or, will every browser treat it as:
http://www.blah.com/blah.php?key=23

Thanks.

Comment: Browsers don't parse URLs. Its the server that matters.

Comment: @Quentin: I've seen JS code that parses the query string and uses the parameters found there.

Comment: In which case it would depend on the JS, not the browser.

Comment: @Quentin: Well, you're technically correct, so let's leave it at that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter at all. You can even add as many `&` as you want, it won't affect the meaning of the URL as the server will remove unused ones and treats `?` semantically as a `&`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work on FF4, IE9 and Chrome, but why tempt fate?

Comment: laziness
and because time=money

Comment: it's slightly more efficient this way